# Why does SQL Server require Office Web Components?

Tags: sql-server

After installing SQL Server 2005 (with SSNS, SSIS and SSAS) I found Office Web Components (OWC) installed as well. My customer is asking why OWC is required I have nothing to say. Any ideas? Is there any additional licensing requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, seems I know what's going on. OWC are installed together with Business Inteligence Development Studio (BIDS). It's required to connect to the OLAP cubes.

Answer (score 1):

Sergejus,

Office components are installed are part of SSIS or SSRS and not with Business Inteligence Development Studio (BIDS). I just succeeded applying MS12-027 hot fix.

Answer (score 0):

They are used for the reports

To be precise - Reporting Services

Comment: I haven't installed SSRS on this machine, only SSNSm SSIS and SSAS